# Jackcess how to insert an image with java

Tags: java, file, insert, jackcess

i am a new user of Jackcess.

I use the addRowFromMap method for insert a new row in the MS Access table, but i can not to insert an image in it.

The table Column have the correct format but i can not to do that.

I try to insert java File format, java bytearray, but nothing to do.

Do you have any suggestions or a documentation link ?

Thanks in advance, Emiliano

Comment: Is it that you are unable to insert *anything* into the "OLE Object" (BLOB) column, or is it that you cannot directly open the image in Access after you have inserted it?

Comment: Hi Gord, if i open the MSAccess file after the insert, the blob attribute contains "long binary data" description but if i try to open it with double click, this is the message "comunication error with ole server or activex controller". The definition of column is correct because i can insert an image with right click in MSAccess. Thanks a lot

Comment: I solved it, I tried it with Java class files and Java byte [], but I had to use OleDb Class.